# phpcassa get_range is too slow

Tags: cassandra, phpcassa

I have CF with 1280 rows. 
Each row has 6 columns. Im trying to $cf->get_range('pq_questions','','',1200) and it gets all rows but too slow(about 4-6 sec)

```
Column Family: pq_questions
                SSTable count: 1
                Space used (live): 668363
                Space used (total): 668363
                Number of Keys (estimate): 1280
                Memtable Columns Count: 0
                Memtable Data Size: 0
                Memtable Switch Count: 0
                Read Count: 0
                Read Latency: NaN ms.
                Write Count: 0
                Write Latency: NaN ms.
                Pending Tasks: 0
                Key cache capacity: 200000
                Key cache size: 1000
                Key cache hit rate: 0.10998439937597504
                Row cache capacity: 1000
                Row cache size: 1000
                Row cache hit rate: 0.0
                Compacted row minimum size: 373
                Compacted row maximum size: 1331
                Compacted row mean size: 574
```

It is strange but read latency in cfstats is `NaN ms` 
When i calling `htop` on debian i see that the most load causes `phpcassa`
I has only one node and use consistency level ONE.
What can cause so slow quering?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing you don't have the [C extension installed](http://thobbs.github.com/phpcassa/installation.html).  Without it, a similar query takes 1-2 seconds for me.  With it installed, the same query takes about 0.2 seconds.

Regarding the NaN read latency, latencies aren't captured for get_range_slices (get_range in phpcassa).

Comment: Tyler, can I request you to response on my question, I think only you can do it here